# Better client side of web-service

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, client

I'm writing client app for web-service using C# and MonoTouch. It has some commands for user session (register, login, logout), messaging (list, write, delete, like), image routines (upload, download) and so on.

I wrote implementation for user session request types, which could be executed asynchronously, like that:

```
{
    public delegate void LoginEventHandler(Session session);
    public delegate void ErrorEventHandler(Error error);
    public delegate void StatusEventHandler(string status);

        public interface IDataProvider
        {
            #region Session
            Session GetSession();

            event LoginEventHandler OnRegistered;
            event ErrorEventHandler OnRegisteredError;
            void Register(Person user);

            event LoginEventHandler OnLoggedIn;
            event ErrorEventHandler OnLoggedInError;
            void Login(Person user);

            event StatusEventHandler OnLoggedOut;
            event ErrorEventHandler OnLoggedOutError;
            void Logout(Session session);
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

**It works**, but even now it's a bit **boring and weak** to implement 2 event handlers with unsubscribing from them later for any requests:

```
dataProvider = new DataProviderService ();
...
appDelegate.dataProvider.OnRegistered += HandleOnRegistered;
appDelegate.dataProvider.OnRegisteredError += HandleOnRegisteredError;
appDelegate.dataProvider.Register(GetPerson());
...
void HandleOnRegistered (Session session)
{
    InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
        appDelegate.settings.Session = session;

        appDelegate.dataProvider.OnRegistered -= HandleOnRegistered;
        appDelegate.dataProvider.OnRegisteredError -= HandleOnRegisteredError;

        Waiter.HideWaiter();
        Console.WriteLine(session.userId);
    }
    );
}

void HandleOnRegisteredError (Error error)
{
    InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
        appDelegate.dataProvider.OnRegistered -= HandleOnRegistered;
        appDelegate.dataProvider.OnRegisteredError -= HandleOnRegisteredError;

        Console.WriteLine(error);
    });
}
```

Any suggestion to improve architecture for further development? Or any material to see how guru's usually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the way I architect this kind of things:

- Lazy-load my controllers
- Each controller is a singleton within the app and stays around the life of the application (I use IoC containers, but you don't have to)
- Make your WCF service (or channel) as singleton as well
- Subscribe to events like these in the constructor of each controller
- Handle `ViewDidLoad` and `ViewDidUnload` appropriately so that most memory can be freed in low memory conditiions
- Check `IsViewLoaded` or visibility in the event, etc. to determine if you need to handle the event

You could unsubscribe in `Dispose` for good measure, but it is not needed.

Comment: If I understood you right, generally you are using same things, but with additional check over double signing to event handlers.

Comment: If your controllers are really singleton, then there is no use for checking if you've subscribed to events twice.